# Populate Alternate ID Fields in Turn Feature Class in ArcGIS 10.5

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, network-dataset, turns

I have a Network Dataset with turns and need to edit some of the edges (I found out some were not planarized yet). Using the [Populate Alternate ID Fields](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/network-analyst-toolbox/populate-alternate-id-fields.htm) tool I keep getting the [Error 030030](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/030001-040000/tool-errors-and-warnings-30026-30050-030030.htm).

The Editor is off and no feature class is in use. I get the error both in ArcMap and ArcCatalog.

Comment: Do you receive the same error if you close both ArcMap and ArcCatalog and then try again? And is the Network Analyst extension checked out?

Comment: Yes, restarting the software doesn't help. I think the Network Analyst is checked because otherwise I would not see the Network Analyst toolbox?! (don't have access to computer right now but will doublecheck on monday)

Comment: I keep getting the Error even with Network Analyst Extension unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer from Esri with the following workaround:

> Add the alternate ID fields in the turn feature class manualy before
>   running the tool: Add fields with names AltID of type Double for
>   the maximum number of edges that you have per turn. This way the error
>   does not appear.